# Geometry tricks for smallest of 2 circles circumscribing points

Tags: geometry, circles, computational-geometry

I’m trying to find which of two circles `A,B,C` and `A,B,D` has a smaller radius, where `A,B,C,D` are points in 2 dimensions (Cartesian), and each circle circumscribes those point triples. I’m ignoring edge cases of collinearity for now.

[image]

I can find the smaller radii easily enough by finding the circle centre for each triple (by using the perpendicular bisector of chords AB and BC, for example), and then finding each radii.

However, I’m wondering, **is there’s any geometry or vector tricks to simplify the math** given two of the points are shared, and I only care about finding which is smaller, not the centre or actual radius. Eventually I want to be able to find the result computationally, so the number of steps is important.

If possible it’d be really great to express answers with vector or geometric reasoning, as I find that much easier to understand than matrices and some other forms.

Thank you very much for taking a look!

Comment: I would take a screenshot of your diagram and post it into your question.

Comment: @John I'd love to, but unfortunately I'm new here and don't have enough reputation to add images. I'd be grateful for you to do so if you're able to.

Comment: ^Just added it, it has to be approved though.

Comment: I thought I’d said already, but thank you John

Comment: ^You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ |AE| \leq |AF| \iff \angle ACB \geq \angle ADB $$

Informal or incomplete "proof":

If $C$ and $D$ are on the same side of line $AB$, then $\angle ACB = \angle ADB$ if and only if the quadrilateral is cyclic. If $D$ is outside the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, then $\angle ADB < \angle ACB$ and $|AF| > |AE|$. If $D$ is inside the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, then $\angle ADB > \angle ACB$ and $|AF| < |AE|$.

If $C$ and $D$ are opposite sides of line $AB$, then let $D'$ be the reflection of $D$ across line $AB$. $\angle AD'B = \angle ADB$, and the conclusions above apply.

So it suffices to determine the two (unsigned) angles and compare them. Or if you have the points in vector coordinates, the most efficient computer calculations are probably

$$ \begin{align*}  \angle ACB &\geq \angle ADB \\
{} \iff \cos \angle ACB &\leq \cos \angle ADB \\
{} \iff \frac{\vec{CA} \cdot \vec{CB}}{|CA|\, |CB|} & \leq \frac{\vec{DA} \cdot \vec{DB}}{|DA|\, |DB|}
\end{align*} $$

(Note the cosines and dot products can be negative. It might be convenient in some cases to square both sides of that last inequality to avoid the magnitude square roots, but that only helps if both have the same sign. If both are negative, squaring reverses the sense of the comparisons.)

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! I've just been toying around with a similar method where I start with the circumradius formula: $R=\frac{|ab| |bc| |ca|}{4 |\triangle abc| }$. Then I can get $|\triangle abc|$ with $\frac{1}{2} |\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}| \frac{(\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b})^\intercal \cdot (\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{c})}{|\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}|}$ (ie. half base by height). Many factors simplify, but not as well as yours yet.

I'm happy to accept your answer once I've given it a day or two for other approaches :)

Answer (score 0):

Any chord is equal to the diameter of the circle, times the sine of an inscribed angle insisting on that chord:
$$
AC=2r\cdot\sin\angle ABC=2r{|(A-B)\times(C-B)|\over AB\cdot BC}
$$
that is:
$$
2r={AB\cdot BC\cdot CA\over|A\times B+B\times C+C\times A|},
$$
where $A\times B=x_Ay_B-y_Ax_B$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I couldn’t accept it as an answer without it using the shared geometry between both circles to find a simplified comparison. Also I think the sign of BxC should be negative? but it’s perhaps more simple before the cross is expanded anyway.